# How to modify the Application List in Gnome 3.22

Tags: gnome, icons

I'm using Gonme 3.22 and want to modify the icons and groups in the Application List (super + A).
I've managed to change the number of rows and columns as well as icon size but now I want to remove some icons I don't need, create new folders and move icons in to and out of them. 
I've tried using Menu Libre (alacarte) to remove apps and dconf editor to create new categories as well as changing .desktop files (/usr/share/applications) to modify the Categories so that they would correspond to the ones created in dconf but nothing worked.
I've read somewhere of an xml file I can modify to change the application list but can't find it anymore...
Anyone know what I can do?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found a solution here,
[developer.gnome.ord/AppFolders/](https://developer.gnome.org/AppFolders/)

I haven't got the translation working (French workstation) and miniature icons in the sub-folders take several reloads of the App list (Super + A) to appear. If I find a solution for translating (maybe a reboot), I'll add it.

Comment: This also helped a lot https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gnome_Applications_Folders